# C# using numbers in an enum

Tags: c#, syntax, enums

This is a valid enum

```
public enum myEnum
{
  a= 1,
  b= 2,
  c= 3,
  d= 4,
  e= 5,
  f= 6,
  g= 7,
  h= 0xff
};
```

But this is not

```
public enum myEnum
{
  1a = 1,
  2a = 2,
  3a = 3,
};
```

Is there a way I can use an number in a enum?  I already have code that would populate dropdowns from enums so it would be quite handy

Comment: No idea why the code tags messed up on this one - sorry!

Comment: Variable names cannot start with number. This being said it is not clear why do you need something like this so cannot provide helpful answer.

Comment: Duplicate question...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952192/how-can-i-create-an-enum-using-numbers

Comment: @DanPuzey its not a proper original, though it looks like.

Comment: I would probably use _1, _2, _3

Answer (score 98, accepted):

No identifier at all in C# may begin with a number (for lexical/parsing reasons).   Consider adding a [Description] attribute to your enum values:

```
public enum myEnum
{
    [Description("1A")]
    OneA = 1,
    [Description("2A")]
    TwoA = 2,
    [Description("3A")]
    ThreeA = 3,
};
```

Then you can get the description from an enum value like this:

```
((DescriptionAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
    typeof(myEnum).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
        .Single(x => (myEnum)x.GetValue(null) == enumValue),    
    typeof(DescriptionAttribute))).Description
```

Based on XSA's comment below, I wanted to expand on how one could make this more readable.  Most simply, you could just create a static (extension) method:

```
public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
{
    return ((DescriptionAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
        value.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
            .Single(x => x.GetValue(null).Equals(value)),
        typeof(DescriptionAttribute)))?.Description ?? value.ToString();
}
```

It's up to you whether you want to make it an extension method, and in the implementation above, I've made it fallback to the enum's normal name if no `[DescriptionAttribute]` has been provided.

Now you can get the description for an enum value via:

```
myEnum.OneA.GetDescription()
```

Comment: Nice Solution; but is there an easier way to retreive the description shorter than these 4 lines ?

Comment: Should also point out that it's not limited to `Enum`s, you can use it for anything you apply the `DescriptionAttirbute` to.

Answer (score 14):

No, there isn't. C# does not allow identifiers to start with a digit.

Application usability note: In your application you should not display code identifiers to the end-user anyway. Think of translating individual enumeration items into user-friendly displayable texts. Sooner or later you'll have to extend the enum with an item whose identifier won't be in a form displayable to the user.

**UPDATE:** Note that the way for attaching displayable texts to enumeration items is being discusses, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914688/whats-the-best-way-to-provide-localization-for-enums/3914790).

Comment: You can use DescriptionAttribute to associate a user-friendly string with each enum value and populate your dropdowns by extracting the attribute values instead of showing the raw enums.

Comment: I needed to define an enumeration for printer types that are 58MM and 80MM. These are user friendly displayable texts :P. Nevertheless, solved with _58mm

Answer (score 10):

An identifier in C# (and most languages) cannot start with a digit.

If you can modify the code that populates a dropdown with the enumeration names, you could maybe have a hack that strips off a leading underscore when populating the dropdown and define your enum like so:

```
public enum myEnum
{
  _1a = 1,
  _2a = 2,
  _3a = 3
};
```

Or if you don't like the underscores you could come up with your own 'prefix-to-be-stripped' scheme (maybe pass the prefix to the constructor or method that will populate the dropdown from the enum).

Answer (score 6):

> Short and crisp 4 line code.

We simply use enums as named integer for items in code,

**so any simplest way is good to go.**

```
public enum myEnum
{
    _1 = 1,
    _2,
    _3,
};
```

Also for decimal values,

```
public enum myEnum
{
    _1_5 = 1,
    _2_5,
    _3_5,
};
```

So while using this in code,

```
int i = cmb1.SelectedIndex(0); // not readable
int i = cmb1.SelectedIndex( (int) myEnum._1_5); // readable
```

Comment: Can you explain how `(int) myEnum._1_5` is more readable than `0`? And to start with, they're not equivalent in your code. It seems like it makes things hard to understand to me.

Comment: _1_5 in a remote code can be understood as 1.5, but 0 cannot be understood as 1.5. Thats how

Comment: You're saying that you have a number, `1.5`, in an array at position `0`, so the most readable way to access the `1.5` is to do `array[(int)myEnum._1_5]`? That's crazy. If at compile-time you knew you needed `1.5` then `double value = 1.5;` is far better than `double value = array[(int)myEnum._1_5];`. Please tell me in what circumstance this increase in verbosity and indirection make sense?

Comment: I have a dropdown which has border values for line in PowerPoint which has values like 1, 1.5, 3, 5 etc which I store in enum. So it's easy for me to get/set index based on these value

Comment: I think I'd have to see your code to understand why it's useful.

Comment: In simple words, when you only have choice to select handful of values from dropdown, and here readable in the sense, 0 doesn't say anything, but _1_5 you can understand what value is choosen.

Comment: Again, I'd have to see actual code to hopefully understand why this is useful.

Answer (score 4):

No way. A valid identifier (ie a valid enumeration member) cannot start with a digit.

Answer (score 4):

Enumerations are no different than variables in terms of naming rules. Therefore, you can't start the name with a number. From [this post](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/sample_chapter/article.php/c11387), here are the main rules for variable naming.

- The name can contain letters, digits, and the underscore character
  (_).

  - The first character of the name must be a letter. The underscore is
    also a legal first character, but its
    use is not recommended at the
    beginning of a name. An underscore is
    often used with special commands, and
    it's sometimes hard to read.
  - Case matters (that is, upper- and lowercase letters). C# is
    case-sensitive; thus, the names count
    and Count refer to two different
    variables.
  - C# keywords can't be used as variable names. Recall that a keyword
    is a word that is part of the C#
    language. (A complete list of the C#
    keywords can be found in Appendix B,
    "C# Keywords.")

Comment: Better yet, the C# Language Specification section on Identifiers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(v=VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 4):

Identifiers can't start with numbers. However, they can contain numbers.

Answer (score -3):

Here is what i came up with as an alternative, where I needed Enums to use in a "for" Loop and a string representation equivalent to use in a Linq query.

> 1. Create enums namespace to be used in "for" Loop.

```
public enum TrayLevelCodes
    {
        None,
        _5DGS,
        _5DG,
        _3DGS,
        _3DG,
        _AADC,
        _ADC,
        _MAAD,
        _MADC
    };
```

> 2. Create strings based on enum created to be used for Linq query

```
public string _5DGS = "\"5DGS\"",
        _5DG = "\"5DG\"",
        _3DGS = "\"3DGS\"",
        _3DG = "\"3DG\"",
        _AADC = "\"AADC\"",
        _ADC = "\"ADC\"",
        _MAAD = "\"MAAD\"",
        _MADC = "\"MADC\"";
```

> 3. Create function that will take an enum value as argument and return corresponding string for Linq query.

```
public string GetCntnrLvlDscptn(TrayLevelCodes enumCode)
        {
            string sCode = "";
            switch (enumCode)
            {
                case TrayLevelCodes._5DGS:
                    sCode = "\"5DGS\"";
                    break;
                case TrayLevelCodes._5DG:
                    sCode = "\"5DG\"";
                    break;
                case TrayLevelCodes._3DGS:
                    sCode = "\"3DGS\"";
                    break;
                case TrayLevelCodes._3DG:
                    sCode = "\"3DG\"";
                    break;
                case TrayLevelCodes._AADC:
                    sCode = "\"AADC\"";
                    break;
                case TrayLevelCodes._ADC:
                    sCode = "\"AAC\"";
                    break;
                case TrayLevelCodes._MAAD:
                    sCode = "\"MAAD\"";
                    break;
                case TrayLevelCodes._MADC:
                    sCode = "\"MADC\"";
                    break;
                default:
                    sCode = "";
                    break;
            }
                return sCode;
        }
```

> 4. Here is how i am using what i created above.

```
for (var trayLevelCode = TrayLevelCodes._5DGS; trayLevelCode <= TrayLevelCodes._MADC; trayLevelCode++)
{
    var TrayLvLst = (from i in pair1.Value.AutoMap
                     where (i.TrayLevelCode == HTMLINFO.GetCntnrLvlDscptn(trayLevelCode))
                     orderby i.TrayZip, i.GroupZip
                     group i by i.TrayZip into subTrayLvl
                     select subTrayLvl).ToList();
    foreach (DropShipRecord tray in TrayLvLst)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: It'd be a lot easier to just use the `Description` attribute.