# When creating enum list, got "Identifier expected" error

Tags: c#, .net, enums

When trying to create  enum list of tabs name, got the "Identifier expected" error (see attached).

What am i doing wrong?[enum list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjWYB.jpg)

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] (in text of your question, not as an external link).

Comment: value can not start with number (2ndOffers is invalid value)

Comment: The problem is your `2ndOffers` enum value, you cannot start an identifier with a digit. It has to be an underscore or a letter. Try using `SecondOffers` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# using numbers in an enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916914/c-sharp-using-numbers-in-an-enum)

Comment: Thanks all, it sure did solved the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `2ndOffers` is not an identifier.

An identifier has to start with an underscore or a letter, it can *contain* digits, *after* that initial character.

So rewrite that identifier to be `SecondOffers` instead.

A technical version of the specification can be found here: [Lexical structure - Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#identifiers) which contains this part:

```
identifier_or_keyword
    : identifier_start_character identifier_part_character*
    ;

identifier_start_character
    : letter_character
    | '_'
    ;

identifier_part_character
    : letter_character
    | decimal_digit_character
    | connecting_character
    | combining_character
    | formatting_character
    ;
```

Basically, it has to start with "identifier_start_character" and can continue with zero or more "identifier_part_character", and "identifier_start_character" can only be a letter or an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

You can't start an identifier with a number in C# 
like

```
2ndOffers
```